# Calculate two array values in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays like

```
    $a1                $b1
0 : A                  10
1:  B                  10
2:  A                  15
3:  A                  20
4: B                   05
5: c                   25
```

now i want to calculate them in same way then result is A=45, B=15 and C=25

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$calc = array_fill_keys($a1,0);
foreach($a1 as $i => $key) {
  $calc[$key] += $b1[$i];
}
```

`$calc` is array of calculated values:

```
[A] => 45,
[B] => 15
etc.
```

Comment: Don't cheat with @, use `$calc = array_fill_keys($a1,0)` to remove the warnings

Comment: can you tell me one more thing that how can i print $calc values in different html cells like A   45

Comment: `echo "<table>"; foreach($calc as $key=>$value) { echo "<tr><td>{$key}</td><td>{$value}</td></tr>"; } echo "</table>";`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already been answered and accepted, and the accepted answer is a lot simpler and more efficient; but purely because I was tempted to try a rather different approach:

```
$a1 = array('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'c');
$b1 = array('10','10','15','20','05','25');

$sumArray = array();
foreach(array_unique($a1) as $key) {
    $arrayElements = array_filter(
                         $a1,
                         function($value) use ($key) {
                             return $value == $key;
                         }
                     );
    $sumArray[$key] = array_sum(
                          array_intersect_key(
                              $b1,
                              array_fill_keys(
                                  array_keys($arrayElements),
                                  NULL
                              )
                          )
                      );
}

var_dump($sumArray);
```